# Weird amount of views on a question

Tags: support

The question [Are there moves in chess that are considered unsporting?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5403/are-there-moves-in-chess-that-are-considered-unsporting) :

[image]

The question got 3k views somehow. I want to know if it got viral somewhere? or someone had too much time on his hands?

Comment: It was on the Stack Exchange "Hot Network Questions" list today. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it went slightly viral when it showed up on the Hot Network Questions list in the right sidebar. Also, views are only counted once per user per day. So one user would have to have a lot more time on his hands than you imagined in order to rack up 3K views by himself... :)